# How to work with SharePoint 2010 in developer machine.?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i am new to SharePoint. We have installed SharePoint 2013 in server. I can access Central admin and etc in developer machine through web browsers. Now i would like to develop a new app in SharePoint. I am not able to open SharePoint in Visual Studio on developer machine. Its shows SharePoint not installed in this system. So, what are the procedures to work with SharePoint in developer machine. We are using Visual Studio 2010. Where to download SharePoint 2010 for developer machine. And what are the requirements for it.?

Answer (score 0):

To develop against SharePoint, you must have SharePoint installed locally.

First you need to decide what's your target version: 2013 or 2010 ?

From your post it seems your target version is SharePoint 2013. For that, you must install SharePoint 2013 on your local machine.

See this post:

`Start: Set up the development environment for SharePoint 2013`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx